# django-autocomplete-light does not work in apache

Tags: django-autocomplete-light

I'm using django-autocomplete-light

```
Django==1.8
django-autocomplete-light==3.1.6
django-easy-select2==1.2.5
django-suit==0.2.13
django-tables2==1.0.4
```

It works fine when I run it in the django development server but it does not load when I set DEBUG=False and run the app in apache.
I've run collectstatic and select2 javascript and css exist and can be downloaded.
The page shows a javascript error that **select2 is not a function**.

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'suit',
    'myapp',
    'dal',
    'dal_select2',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django_extensions',
    'simple_history',
    'django_tables2',
    'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
)
```

admin page order of content:

```
<link href="/static/autocomplete_light/vendor/select2/dist/css/select2.css" type="text/css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/static/autocomplete_light/select2.css" type="text/css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/admin/RelatedObjectLookups.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/jquery.init.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/actions.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/autocomplete_light/jquery.init.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/autocomplete_light/autocomplete.init.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/autocomplete_light/vendor/select2/dist/js/select2.full.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/autocomplete_light/select2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/related-widget-wrapper.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/calendar.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/admin/DateTimeShortcuts.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This was wierd. After spending a lot of effort playing with this, I wiped out the static folder content and ran collectstatic django command from scratch and it's working now. When I diff it, I see that there are changes in admin and select2.js so maybe they've updated the packages  to fix the issue.